# Why is the Fragment of a Uri ignored in the Equals method?

Tags: c#, uri

I'm trying to maintain a collection of objects based on their URI:

```
public class ConceptCollection : KeyedCollection<Uri, Concept> {
    protected override Uri GetKeyForItem(Concept item) {
        return item.Uri;
    } 
}
```

However, the URI regularly only differs based on the Fragment of the Uri.  So, the following causes an error:

```
ConceptCollection wines = new ConceptCollection();
Concept red = new Concept("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#RedWine");
Concept white = new Concept("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#WhiteWine");
wines.Add(red);
wines.Add(white); // Error: An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f83xtf15.aspx:

> The Equals method compares the two
>   instances without regard to user
>   information ( UserInfo) and fragment (
>   Fragment) parts that they might
>   contain. For example, given the URIs
>   http://www.contoso.com/index.htm#search
>   and
>   http://user:password@www.contoso.com/index.htm,
>   the Equals method would return true.

I'm resigned to having to hack around this.  But why does it behave this way?  I can see the logic for user-info, but not for fragment.

Comment: Any of the RDF frameworks that I have worked with have had to implement their own Uri class as the .NET System.Uri implementation does not maintain the purity of the original Uri.  You could use System.Uri.OriginalString to avoid this on a smaller project... similar problems will crop up over and over again though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> 4.1. Fragment Identifier
>
> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after
>   the    retrieval action has been successfully completed.  **As such, it is not part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.**

The emphasis added is mine and is the reason the fragment is not considered in the Uri.Equals implementation.

In your example, the URI for the resource you are retrieving is: http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl

The fragments are processed by the user agent and have no meaning to or influence on the actual retrieval of the resource.

Comment: Nicely spotted.  I guess my issue now is with the W3C using fragments as unique identifiers when referencing ontology elements.  (The samples I used were consistent with their OWL documentation).  Cheers.

Comment: @Adrian: Uri isn't a sealed class. You could accomplish this by deriving your own class from Uri that modifies the Equals behavior to also look at the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess because 2 URIs that are identical apart from the fragment still refer to the same resource, just a different location within the resource.

So if you're asking the question 'are these the same resource?' then you could argue that it's correct to ignore the fragment.

Comment: Here's a link to W3C description of fragments in URLs: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#h-4.1.1

Comment: I can see the basic logic.  But once you specify a fragment, aren't you specifying only a portion of the resource (i.e. the fragment).  E.g. http://me/body#leftHand versus http://me/body#rightFoot.

Comment: @Adrian: The entire resource must still be retrieved by the user agent and then the fragment can be processed to point the UA to the appropriate section/fragment of the full resource. There is no way to retrieve only part of the resource.